# .then is not defined on devicesIsReady

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angular-promise

I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: loginService.verificarSesion(...).then is not a function

I think I don't understand perfectly **promise**

I need to check if the user is logged in on deviceIsReady on my apache-cordova app.
This is the part of the function:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $http, $state, loginService) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        loginService.verificarSesion()
            .then(function(usuario) {
                if(usuario == 1){
                    //es complejo
                    $state.go('app.home');
                }
                else if(usuario == 2){
                    //es usuario comun
                    $state.go('app.home-usuario');
                }
                else{
                    //no se renococió ningún usuario válido
                    $state.go('app.login');
                }
            })
            .catch(function(e){
               console.log('error trying to find the user');
            });
    });
})
.config(function($urlRouterProvider) {
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');
});
```

**Service:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('example.login')
        .factory('loginService', loginService);

    loginService.$inject = ['$http','remoteDataService', '$q','_','localStorageService'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function loginService($http, remoteDataService, $q,_, localStorageService){ 
        var token = 'token';
        var usuario = 'usuario';

        var service = {
            verificarSesion: verificarSesion
        };
        return service;

        //funcion para saber si hay una sesión activa
        function verificarSesion() {
            var usuariologueado = localStorageService.get(token) || [];
            if (usuariologueado == []){
                return [];
            }
            return localStorageService.get(usuario);
        }

        //generar error si hubo un problema
        function generarError(e){
            if (e.message) {
                return $q.reject(e.message);
            }
            return $q.reject('Hubo un problema al conectarse al servidor. Intente nuevamente.');
        }

    }
})();
```

If the user is logged in I have to sen the user to another view.

What I'm doing wrong?
**Thanks!**

Comment: The indentation here is inconsistent and it's making your code hard to follow. Why are you indenting the closing brackets on `if`? This is an extremely unruly style. The reason I'm complaining is because callback and promise-driven code needs to be very carefully nested or it won't work out like you expect.

Comment: I copied the code to sublime tex and it change the identation @tadman

Comment: I'm assuming your `localStorageService.get()` method does not return a promise, just a value immediately?

Comment: @GregL Well... is a component, I used it like the tutorial said. I think may be not return a promise. I think this is the component: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: from the documentation - **get** `Directly get a value from local storage` ... wrap `localStorageService.get(usuario);` in a `Promise.resolve()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty clear in your code that the function `verificarSesion` can return an empty Array, of course an Array doesn't have `.then()` method.

According to the doc [here](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage#get), your call to `localStorageService.get(usuario)` return whatever value you stored in the `localStorage`. Are you sure that you store a `Promise` with the key `'usuario'`?

I suppose you would need something like this:

```
    function verificarSesion() {
        var usuariologueado = localStorageService.get(token) || [];

        if (usuariologueado == []){
            return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
                $http
                    // change this if you need to post application/x-www-form-urlencoded
                    .post('login_url', {username: usuario, password: 'abc'})
                    .then(
                        function (resp) {
                            // initiate the session in the localStorage
                            localStorageService.set(usuario, resp.data);
                            res(localStorageService.get(usuario));
                        },
                        function(err) {
                            // error occured, notify user
                            rej(err);
                        }
                    );
            });
        }
        return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
            // resolve immediately
            res(localStorageService.get(usuario));
        });
    }
```

There are still many issues with the code above, for instance, what is `usuariologueado` used for? what is the `token`? why do you get the user session directly from `localStorage` with something seems to be the `username`? etc

If you want a user session, you can look at `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`.